# Fortran code compiled with gfortran in visual code, when I debug with GDB it does not detect out of bounds

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, gfortran

How can I make GDB detect and provide an error when writing out of bounds? This is my json file

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Run GDB",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",   
    }
]
```

}

Comment: did you apply any sanitizers when building?

Comment: How did you compile? Use `-fcheck=all` to enable runtime checks. Alernatively, you can try `-fsanitize=address` for address sanitizations. gdb will not do this for you.